# Swift: NSDate returning nil when added to coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate

When I try to add the `NSDate` to newWorkout; code line:

```
newWorkout.setValue(currentTime, forKey: "workoutDate")
```

It returns nil even though when I print currentTime just before the line of code is executed it returns the correct `NSDate`. The core data in saving is to an entity called Workout, with two attributes workoutTime of type `Int16` and workoutDate of type Date.

```
   let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


    let newWorkout = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Workout", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Workout

    let totalTimeConverted = Int16(totalTime)

    let currentTime = NSDate()
    print(currentTime)

    // Add parameters
    newWorkout.setValue(NSInteger(totalTimeConverted), forKey: "workoutTime")
    newWorkout.setValue(currentTime, forKey: "workoutDate")


    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error saving data")
    }


    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Workout")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if results.count > 0 {

        for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

            let time = item.valueForKey("workoutTime")
            print(time)
            let workoutDate = item.valueForKey("workoutDate")
            print(workoutDate)
            print(time!, workoutDate!)

        }
        }
    } catch{
        print("Error loading data")
    }
```

Comment: What is the `type` of `workoutDate` in your `entity` definition?

Comment: it is of type 'Date'

Comment: What is the count of `result` and log out value of `print(time)`

Comment: print time works fine. It prints the value needed (in this case 59)